# Storage Account not listed for "Register Source" in Purview account

Tags: azure-purview

I am trying to register multiple data storage account of type ADLS gen2 in my purview account.

I only see 1 ADLS gen2 storage account 'prodstaticblob' not the other 2.
Can someone please guide me what I am missing here.

[image]

[image]

My Purview account is in 'POC' resource group, still its not able to detect storage account from same resource group.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your created storage accounts are Azure Data Lake storage accounts or Blob storage by using the Azure CLI script below:

```
az resource show --name <storageAccountName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName>  --resource-type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"  --query properties.isHnsEnabled
```

If the storage account is an Azure Data Lake storage account, you will get an output of "true" as shown below:

[image]

While creating an Azure storage account, enable `Hierarchical Namespace` as shown below:

[image]

This will create an Azure Data Lake storage account. The storage accounts will then be available in the Purview account, as shown below:

[image]